# Highlighting of cells disappears in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

In excel, I change the border color of cells. The cursor turns into a little pen with which I can click on the border of cells and change its color. But after I do this, I try to highlight some cells and the grey shading and green outline on the cells does not appear. How can I fix this?

Comment: How exactly, are you *...try to highlight some cells...* and how are those cells related to the cells for which you have changed the border colors? Perhaps you can provide a image clip of the problem?

Comment: By highlighting cells I mean clicking and dragging on a random cell whose border wasn't one of the ones that I changed.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. In my Excel 2007 the highlighted (selected) area has a black border and the fill color is a bluish gray (except for the first cell in the selection). Changing the border color and thickness, to a few alternative colors I tried with, of a number of cells, has no effect on the border and fill of selected cells